# WorkFront / AtTask API Authentication Error

Tags: attask, workfront-api

When I am trying to get a session ID for Authentication by using:
/attask/api/v9.0/login?username=admin&password=user.
When I run it, it tells me I am not logged in. How am I supposed to be logged in to log in?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the 'you are not logged in' message comes from Workfront thinking you are making an api call without authentication, so perhaps you have a typo in your call so that it's invoking another method and failing to authenticate before checking to see if the endpoint is valid.

I've seen some issues with api authentication for lower-permission users, like review/collaborate licensed users. What license is allocated to the user that you are trying to login as?

You would generate a session ID with the following:

```
POST https://<domain>.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/login?username=admin&password=user
```

However, it's strongly encouraged that you use an API key instead for security purposes. Also note that if you have symbols in your username/password, you may need to URLEncode them to prevent your language from misreading them.

Comment: Yes, that is what I use to try to generate the session ID and it tells me that I am not logged in. I will check on the API Key.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the login api in postman and it worked for me
url : https://.workfront.com/attask/api/v5.0/login
and in the body under x-www-form-urlencoded give your credential like username and password